# How do I turn entire stdin into a command line argument verbatim?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, stdin

#### Attempt 1

```
xargs -I '{}' -0 -n 1 myprogram --arg '{}' --other-options
```

<s>But that does not preserve zero bytes. Also the program may run multiple times.</s> But instead of failing in case of zero byte creeping into stdin, it runs program multiple times.

#### Attempt 2

```
myprogram --arg "`cat`" --other-options
```

But that does not preserve trailing whitespace.

#### Attempt 3

```
bash -c 'read -r -d "" INPUT ; myprogram --arg "$INPUT" --other-options'
```

Seems to mess with terminal, also fails to preserve trailing whitespace.

---

How do I do it properly, reliably, readably, compatibly?

Comment: It looks like attempts #2 and #3 fail to preserve a trailing **newline**, but they do preserve trailing whitespace (like space characters) that precedes the newline. Very interesting question, +1.

Comment: Why do you need to preserve NUL? They are used as end marker in C style strings, any kind of horror that needs that would do better using files for passing such data instead, I suppose.

Comment: Good point, @TNW. In fact [it is impossible to have NUL bytes in command line arguments](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160598/representing-quoting-nul-on-the-command-line), not merely inadvisible or horrible.

Comment: @Celada, @TNW, Then the remaining issue is multiple processes from `xargs` instead of one...

Comment: @TNW, I wanted it to handle binary data as well, but now I see that it's not a good idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[It is impossible to have NUL bytes in command line arguments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/160598/representing-quoting-nul-on-the-command-line), so the question is what do you want to happen in case there *are* NUL bytes in the standard input.

As you've noted, your candidate solution #1 runs the command multiple times in this case. That's not ideal. But there is no ideal solution that lets you handle true binary input. As I see it, your only other reasonable options here are to:

- delete the NUL bytes and proceed

  - insert `tr -d '\0' |` before `xargs`
- translate the NUL bytes to something else and proceed

  - insert `tr '\0'  something-else |` before `xargs` (if `something-else` is a single byte)
- abort and bail in case there are NUL bytes

  - with bash or ksh93 (except if the input contains a single null byte at the end, in which case it is silently deleted):

    ```
    { read -r -d '' input;
      if [ "$(wc -c)" = 0 ]; then
        printf %s "$input" | xargs …;
      else
        echo 1>&2 "Null bytes detected, bailing out"
        exit 2
      fi
    }
    ```
  - with zsh (and not with other shells such as bash, ksh or dash):

    ```
    input=$(<&0)
      if [[ $input != *$'\0'* ]]; then
        printf %s "$input" | xargs …;
      else
        echo 1>&2 "Null bytes detected, bailing out"
        exit 2
      fi
    ```
  - Or use a temporary file.
- truncate the input after the first NUL byte

  - insert `tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | head -n 1 | tr '\0\n' '\n\0'` before `xargs` (assuming your `head` is null-safe)

Comment: Waiting for `not that easy` to be filled in before accepting. I doubt it would be "properly, reliably, readably, compatibly" although...

Comment: @Vi. I'm probably not going to fill those in :-( I agree with you not accepting too: this is not really a full answer.

Comment: @Vi. See my edit

Comment: Well done, @Gilles. Clever trick to swap NUL and newline and then use `head`. Thanks.